# CSS flexbox and justify-content

Tags: css, flexbox

For a layout, I need to have three flex items (rows) in a flex container, and I want them justified as `space-between`... The first row will contain some cloud tags, the second a price, and the third a Read more link.

But there will be cases where for specific items, only the last row (the Read more) will need to exist.

So, in those cases, for uniformity, I want the Read more link to be placed at the bottom of the container; but `space-between` doesn't help much towards that approach...

What can I do to have a fallback `justify-content` property set to `end` for when there is only one child item?

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
}

.tags span {
  background-color: #f0f;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%
}

.read-more {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <span>tag 1</span><span>tag2</span><span>tag 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    $100
  </div>
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of `justify-content` on the container, use `auto` margins on the items.  https://jsfiddle.net/73hkugaq/ (The explanation is in the duplicate.)

Answer (score 1):

If you are able/willing to change the order of the flex-items in your HTML code, you can reverse them there and use `flex-direction: column-reverse;` on the container. That way the "read more" element is the first flex-item and due to the reversed direction at the bottom of the container:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
}

.tags span {
  background-color: #f0f;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%
}

.read-more {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    $100
  </div>
  <div class="tags">
    <span>tag 1</span><span>tag2</span><span>tag 3</span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can give the container a `position: relative;` tag, the `.read-more` class, and the `:only-child` pseudo class. Then when it is the only child in the container, it will add the attributes `position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0;` to it.

This moves it to the bottom right of the container. The `justify-content: end !important;` doesn't move the container to where you want it to be.

Example:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #aaa;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  position:relative;
}

.tags {
  display: flex;
}

.tags span {
  background-color: #f0f;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 0 0 0 10px;
}

.price {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ff0;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 150%
}

.read-more {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #0ff;
  padding: 10px;
}

.read-more:only-child{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    right:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="tags">
    <span>tag 1</span><span>tag2</span><span>tag 3</span>
  </div>
  <div class="price">
    $100
  </div>
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="read-more">
    <a href="#">Read more >></a>
  </div>
</div>
```